# Using buttons as touchscreen controls for javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm making a webpage that is just a place to take a break, and a lot of my users are on touchscreen, so I'm trying to implement touchscreen controls into the games, but it's not working and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. The arrow key controls still work, but not the buttons.

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320" ></canvas>
<script>
function playGame() {   var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = canvas.width/2;
var y = canvas.height-30;
var dx = 2;
var dy = -2;
var ballRadius = 10;
var paddleHeight = 10;
var paddleWidth = 75;
var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth) / 2;
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var difficulty = 10
var score = 0
var gameRunning = false
var paused = false
function paddleMoveLeft(){   paddleX -= 5;
    if (paddleX < 0){
        paddleX = 0;
    }}
function paddleMoveRight(){  paddleX += 5;
    if (paddleX + paddleWidth > canvas.width){
        paddleX = canvas.width - paddleWidth;
    }}
function playPause(){
if(paused === true){paused = false}
else {paused = true}
}
function drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function drawPaddle() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height-paddleHeight, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}
function drawScore() {
    ctx.font = "24px ";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Score: "+score, 8, 20);
}
function draw() {
 if (paused === false){
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawBall();
    drawPaddle();
   drawScore();
   x += dx;
    y += dy;
   
if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
}
if(y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
} else if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius) {
    if(x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddleWidth) {
        dy = -dy;
        difficulty = difficulty + 0.5;
  score = score + 1;
  }
    else {
        alert("GAME OVER! you scored " + score);
         ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        clearInterval(interval);
   canvas.style.display = 'none';
   }
}

if(rightPressed) {
  paddleMoveRight();
}
else if(leftPressed) {
  paddleMoveLeft();
}

}
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = true;
    }
}

function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if(e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
        rightPressed = false;
    }
    else if(e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
        leftPressed = false;
    }
}
var interval = setInterval(draw, difficulty);}
 
    
 
</script>
<div style = 'width: 30%; margin: auto;'>
<button style = 'font-size:large;' onclick = 'paddleMoveLeft()'> left</button>
<button style = 'font-size: large;' onclick = 'paddleMoveRight()'> right</button>
</div>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just by opening the console, it will tells you what's wrong.

So far, you call `paddleMoveLeft` in html but it's not globally defined, as it is inside the `playGame` method. [About scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)